# How to create a table as select in pyspark.sql

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to create a table on spark using a select statement?

I do the following

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

spark_df = sqlCtx.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("./data/documents_topics.csv")
spark_df.registerTempTable("my_table")

sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE my_table_2 AS SELECT * from my_table")
```

but I get the error

> /Users/user/anaconda/bin/python
>   /Users/user/workspace/Outbrain-Click-Prediction/test.py Using Spark's
>   default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use
>   sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). 17/01/21 17:19:43 WARN NativeCodeLoader:
>   Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using
>   builtin-java classes where applicable Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o19.sql. :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator
>   'CreateHiveTableAsSelectLogicalPlan CatalogTable(     Table: `my_table_2`
>     Created: Sat Jan 21 17:19:53 EST 2017   Last Access: Wed Dec 31
>   18:59:59 EST 1969     Type: MANAGED   Storage(InputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, OutputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat)), false;;
>   'CreateHiveTableAsSelectLogicalPlan CatalogTable(     Table: `my_table_2`
>     Created: Sat Jan 21 17:19:53 EST 2017   Last Access: Wed Dec 31
>   18:59:59 EST 1969     Type: MANAGED   Storage(InputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, OutputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat)), false : 
>   +- Project [document_id#0, topic_id#1, confidence_level#2] :     +- SubqueryAlias my_table :        +-
>   Relation[document_id#0,topic_id#1,confidence_level#2] csv
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/user/workspace/Outbrain-Click-Prediction/test.py", line 16, in
>   
>       sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE my_table_2 AS SELECT * from my_table")   File
>   "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/context.py",
>   line 360, in sql
>       return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)   File "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 543, in sql
>       return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)   File
>   "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "/Users/user/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 69, in deco
>       raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "unresolved operator
>   'CreateHiveTableAsSelectLogicalPlan CatalogTable(\n\tTable:
>   `my_table_2`\n\tCreated: Sat Jan 21 17:19:53 EST 2017\n\tLast Access:
>   Wed Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 1969\n\tType: MANAGED\n\tStorage(InputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, OutputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat)),
>   false;;\n'CreateHiveTableAsSelectLogicalPlan CatalogTable(\n\tTable:
>   `my_table_2`\n\tCreated: Sat Jan 21 17:19:53 EST 2017\n\tLast Access:
>   Wed Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 1969\n\tType: MANAGED\n\tStorage(InputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, OutputFormat:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat)), false\n:
>   +- Project [document_id#0, topic_id#1, confidence_level#2]\n:     +- SubqueryAlias my_table\n:        +-
>   Relation[document_id#0,topic_id#1,confidence_level#2] csv\n"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've corrected this issue by using `HiveContext` instead of `SQLContext` as below:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlCtx= HiveContext(sc)

spark_df = sqlCtx.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("./data/documents_topics.csv")
spark_df.registerTempTable("my_table")

sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE my_table_2 AS SELECT * from my_table")
```

Comment: It's worth noting, now, that `HiveContext()` is [deprecated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.HiveContext) as of Spark 2.2. 

The correct answer now uses `SparkSession.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()` instead.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in a more native PySpark manner, e.g. spark_df.registerPersistentTable('my_table_2')  -- I know registerPersistentTable is not an actual method but something similar?

Comment: here one problem, data also copy with schema, is there any way to copy only schema

Answer (score 0):

You should first do a select and assign it to a dataframe variable and then register it with `registerTempTable` as you do with the dataframe created from the CSV file