# pyspark's window functions fn.avg() only output same data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, isnull
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark= SparkSession.builder.appName(" ").getOrCreate()
file = "D:\project\HistoryData.csv"
lines = pd.read_csv(file)
spark_df=spark.createDataFrame(cc,['id','time','average','max','min'])

temp = Window.partitionBy("time").orderBy("id").rowsBetween(-1, 1)

df = spark_df.withColumn("movingAvg",fn.avg("average").over(temp))

df.show()
```

But it output this:
[image]

It output the same data,and some data is disappear.

Comment: The code is correct. The output is correct because you've partitioned by time column and I can't see duplicates in that, atleast in the window. I think you should use `Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-1, 1)`

Comment: It doesn't work:(

Comment: Convert your time column into a `datetime` column.

Comment: Please describe the results you expect. If you want the average over the 3 dates surrounding each row (i.e. values for previous date + this date + next date / 3), you should remove the `partition` completely and simply use `orderBy("time")` in your window function.